# How to manage command line arguments in docker run command?

Tags: command-line-arguments, docker

I want to run this command inside a container: `java -jar bin/felix.jar > log.txt`

If I manually do:

```
frog@gooseberry:~/path$ sudo docker run -it 5fe6598e0648 /bin/bash
root@9beabfb5e852:/path# java -jar bin/felix.jar > log.txt
[... program running ...]
```

Everything works, but if I try to launch it with:

```
frog@gooseberry:~/path$ sudo docker run -d 5fe6598e0648 "java -jar bin/felix.jar > log.txt"
```

I get the following error:

```
857bb5fcdbd7a315517bc9031d65b26abcaaad1fac7a29574e39a0289d0d77a3
2014/10/20 10:20:53 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 857bb5fcdbd7a315517bc9031d65b26abcaaad1fac7a29574e39a0289d0d77a3: exec: "java -jar bin/felix.jar > log.txt": stat java -jar bin/felix.jar > log.txt: no such file or directory
```

I get the same error if I try to use the inverted commas `''` instead of the double commas `""`.

I want to use commas because of `> log.txt` part, that otherwise would be interpreted by the terminal running on the host machine.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26307592/2356207) suggest to use the `-c` option of `/bin/bash`. It bypasses the problem (and it works), but there is a solution provided by Docker to this problem? How command line arguments should be managed with the command `docker run`?

Comment: Have you tried to supply the full path to 'java'?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @Rob3 as I told in the question, I already have a solution, but I was looking for the "best" method (how it *should* be done) to manage command line arguments in Docker

Answer (score 3):

the '>' is getting interpreted in the local env.

This will work:

```
sudo docker run -d 5fe6598e0648 -c "java -jar bin/felix.jar > log.txt"
```

The default entrypoint is /bin/sh - you can pass the arg to this as a string with the -c option.

Docker provide the CLI option to set you own --entrypoint inline, a default in your Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT. You could set either of these to be include the -c.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution you suggested is the same I cited in my answer. In addition of `-c` bash option, Is there an official suggested way to manage command line arguments in Docker?

Comment: Don't think the issue is with Docker, rather how the shell processes the command line args.

Comment: We'll not sure I follow what you want (your command needs to be run by something). You have a CMD/run command and and ENTRYPOINT/--entrypoint which is what the command is passed to. the entrypoint and command are concatenated.